# How to write test cases for a Program.cs code, without main method or no any method inside?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, xunit

I am using .Net 6.0

I have a file in my project : **Program.cs**, containing registration and mapping code for controllers and services.

like:

```
builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddServices();
```

Now, I want to write, test cases for these lines of code, but there is no any method to call from the [Fact] method, inside the program.cs. Not even the main() method.

Can somebody please put some light on how can we cover this code with our test cases ?

Comment: Move this code to a class method that you can test.

Comment: Yes, I have applied a similar approach, but only used the extension methods instead of normal ones.

Answer (score 1):

When you create a new web application in VS2022, there's a checkbox ["Do not use top-level statements"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/tutorials/top-level-statements). If you leave it unchecked, you get what you're seeing in `Program.cs`. If you do check it, you'll get:

```
namespace WebApplication1
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
        /* Everything exactly as you see in your Program.cs, but indented */
        }
    }
}
```

So if you do envisage wanting to call this method in tests (slightly odd, but okay), I'd recommend using this option rather than creating a separate method to call from `Program.cs`.

Even if you do get that checkbox option wrong during project creation, you should hopefully see that it's not tricky to transform between the two forms, using the above as a template (and adjusting namespace name)

Comment: Thanks, @Damien_The_Unbeliever , That surely make some valuable additions to my knowledge, but the extension method approach is more suitable for my situation.

Answer (score 0):

Followed below steps to complete my code coverage:

1. Created an extension method for WebApplicationBuilder within a new static class.
2. Moved the testable code from Program.cs to the extension method.
3. Wrote the test cases for the extension method.